# Why is my React component state showing up in my url?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I have a login component in my cra app, and my state is showing up in my url, both in dev and production. I've replaced the email with {email}.

http://localhost:3000/?user={email}&password=password

I have no clue why this is happening. I have several other components, none of which exhibit the same behavior. I've also confirmed this is coming from the react component and not any of the route handling (I renamed the state and the url changed in kind).

How do I fix this?

```
import React from 'react';
import '../../App.css';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import * as actions from '../../actions';
import LoginButton from './LoginButton';

class Card extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
        this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    state = {
        user: "",
        password: ""
      };

    handleInputChange(event) {
        const target = event.target;
        const value = target.type === 'checkbox' ? target.checked : target.value;
        const name = target.name;

        this.setState({
            [name]: value
        });
    }

    onSubmit(){
        this.props.login(this.state.user, this.state.password);
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <div style={styles.container}>
                <form style={styles.form}>
                <div style={styles.formContainer}>
                    <div style={styles.block}>
                        <div style={{display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'row'}}>
                            <i class="fas fa-user-circle" style={styles.iconPosition}></i>
                            <div style={{display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column', flex: 5}}>
                                <div style={{display: 'flex', alignItems: 'start', marginBottom: '15px', fontFamily: 'Ubuntu', fontSize: '14pt'}}>
                                    EMAIL
                                </div>
                                <input 
                                type="text" 
                                name="user"
                                value={this.state.user}
                                onChange={this.handleInputChange} 
                                placeholder='john.snow@solidcad.ca'
                                style={{fontFamily: 'Ubuntu', fontSize: '10px', border: 'none'}}
                                /> 
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div style={styles.block}>
                        <div style={{display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'row'}}>
                            <i class="fas fa-unlock-alt" style={styles.iconPosition}></i>
                            <div style={{display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column', flex: 5}}>
                                <div style={{display: 'flex', alignItems: 'start', marginBottom: '15px', fontFamily: 'Ubuntu', fontSize: '14pt'}}>
                                    PASSWORD
                                </div>
                                <input 
                                    type="password" 
                                    name="password" 
                                    value={this.state.password}
                                    onChange={this.handleInputChange}
                                    placeholder='*****'
                                    style={{fontFamily: 'Ubuntu', fontSize: '10px', border: 'none'}}
                                />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <LoginButton label='LOGIN' onClick={this.onSubmit}/>
                </div>

              </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default connect(null, actions)(Card);
```

This is the app component that contains the login screen and the login:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import './App.css';
import Configurator from './components/Configurator';
import LoginScreen from './components/Login/LoginScreen';
import * as actions from './actions';

const Dashboard = () => <h2>Dashboard</h2>

class App extends Component {

  componentDidMount(){
    this.props.fetchUser();
  }

  renderContent() {
      switch (this.props.auth) {
        case null:
          return <LoginScreen />;
        default:
          return (
            <BrowserRouter>
                  <Route exact path="/" component={Configurator}/>
                  {/* <Route path="/dashboard/" component={Dashboard}/>    */}
            </BrowserRouter>
          )
      }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App" style={styles.container}>
        {this.renderContent()}
      </div>
    );
  };
}

function mapStateToProps({ auth, desAut }) {
  return { auth, desAut };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(App);
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: can you share the code for `LoginButton` component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`preventDefault` is what you're looking for, you can change the button type to submit in the `LoginButton` component like this `<input type="submit" value="Login"/>` and then

```
<form 
  style={styles.form} 
  onSubmit={(e) => { 
   e.preventDefault();
   this.onSubmit(); 
  }}
>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide an `onSubmit` handler on your `form` like this:

```
<form onSubmit={(event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  ...process form data...
  }>
  ...
</form>
```